# error "org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 404 null" in spring boot

Tags: java, spring

I get authorization code and also i get access token and refresh token in console but after that it throws error when user logins and approves in path `/oauth/authorize` and page redirects to `http://localhost:8090/showEmployees?code=kc0KuO` there we find error in console

> org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 404 null
>
> Whitelabel Error Page
>
> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing 
>    this as a fallback.
>       Mon Nov 12 19":59:32 IST 2018
>       There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
>       404 null

I'm actually not getting the error for a long time

```
@Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {       

        @Autowired
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager; 
        @Autowired
        private RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory; 
        @Autowired
        private TokenStore tokenStore;
        @Autowired
        private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsServiceImpl;
        @Autowired
        private AuthenticationProviderImpl authenticationProviderImpl;

        @Bean
        public TokenStore tokenStore() {
            return new RedisTokenStore(connectionFactory);
        }    

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer 
        configurer) throws Exception {

            configurer
            .inMemory()
            .withClient(Constants.CLIENT_ID)
            .secret(Constants.CLIENT_SECRET)
            .authorizedGrantTypes(Constants.GRANT_TYPE_PASSWORD, Constants.AUTHORIZATION_CODE, Constants.REFRESH_TOKEN)                 
            .scopes(Constants.SCOPE_READ, Constants.SCOPE_WRITE, Constants.TRUST).authorities("CLIENT")         
            .accessTokenValiditySeconds(Constants.ACCESS_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS)
            .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(Constants.REFRESH_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS);
        }   

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
            oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
            .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
        }    

        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProviderImpl);        
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {

            endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
            endpoints.userDetailsService(userDetailsServiceImpl);
            endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore);
        }
    }
```

SucurityConfig Class:

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {   

        @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
            web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**");
        }   

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll().antMatchers("/user/getEmployeesList")
                .hasAnyRole("ADMIN").anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin()
                .permitAll().and().logout().permitAll();

            http.csrf().disable();
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationMgr) throws Exception {
            authenticationMgr.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("admin")
                .authorities("ROLE_ADMIN");
        }

    }
```

class ResourceServer

```
@Configuration
        @EnableResourceServer
        class ResourceServer extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
            //Here we specify to allow the request to the url /user/getEmployeesList with valid access token and scope read 
            @Override
            public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
                http.requestMatchers().antMatchers("/user/getEmployeesList/**").and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest()
                        .access("#oauth2.hasScope('read')");
            }
        }




class Employee

public class Employee {

            private String empId;
            private String empName;

            ...getters/setters
        }
```

This is controller for server side:

```
    @Controller
    public class ServerEmployeeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/getEmployeesList", method = RequestMethod.GET)

        public List<Employee> getEmployeesList() {
            List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
            Employee emp = new Employee();
            emp.setEmpId("emp1");
            emp.setEmpName("emp1");
            employees.add(emp);
            return employees;

        }
    }
```

This is the Controller for client side:

```
    @Controller
    public class ClientEmployeeController {

        private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmployeeController.class); 

        @RequestMapping(value = "/getEmployees", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        //@GetMapping(value="/getEmployees")
        public ModelAndView getEmployeeInfo() {
            logger.info("inside employee controller");
           return new ModelAndView("getEmployees");
        }       

    @RequestMapping(value = "/showEmployees", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView showEmployees(@RequestParam("code") String code) throws JsonProcessingException, IOException {
            ResponseEntity<String> response = null;
            System.out.println("Authorization Ccode------" + code);

            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

            String credentials = "phynart-client:phynart-secret";
            String encodedCredentials = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(credentials.getBytes()));

            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
            headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedCredentials);

            HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);

            String access_token_url = "http://localhost:8080/oauth/token";
            access_token_url += "?code=" + code;
            access_token_url += "&grant_type=authorization_code";
            access_token_url += "&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8090/showEmployees";

            response = restTemplate.exchange(access_token_url, HttpMethod.POST, request, String.class);

            System.out.println("Access Token Response ---------" + response.getBody());

            // Get the Access Token From the recieved JSON response
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(response.getBody());
            String token = node.path("access_token").asText();

            String url = "http://localhost:8080/user/getEmployeesList";

            // Use the access token for authentication
            HttpHeaders headers1 = new HttpHeaders();
            headers1.add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
            HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers1);
            logger.info("error11");


            ResponseEntity<Employee[]> employees = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, Employee[].class);

            System.out.println(employees);

            Employee[] employeeArray = employees.getBody();

            ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("showEmployees");
            model.addObject("employees", Arrays.asList(employeeArray));
            return model;
        }
    }
```

jsp page in client side:

```
    <%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Get Employees</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3 style="color: red;">Get Employee Info</h3>

        <div id="getEmployees">
            <form:form action="http://localhost:8080/oauth/authorize"
                method="post" modelAttribute="emp">
                <p>
                    <label>Enter Employee Id</label>
                     <input type="text" name="response_type" value="code" /> 
                     <input type="text" name="client_id" value="phynart-client" />
                     <input type="text" name="redirect_uri" value="http://localhost:8090/showEmployees" />
                     <input type="text" name="scope" value="read" /> 
                     <input type="SUBMIT" value="Get Employee info" />
            </form:form>
        </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

jsp page in client side:

```
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
    <%@page session="false"%>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Show Employees</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h3 style="color: red;">Show All Employees</h3>
        <ul>
            <c:forEach var="listValue" items="${employees}">
                <li>${listValue}</li>
            </c:forEach>
        </ul>
    </body>
    </html>
```

log file:

> Authorization Ccode------kc0KuO Access Token Response
>   ---------{"access_token":"2148555e-424f-4c00-b144-b5b3f8ee9336","token_type":"bearer","refresh_token":"cc2a35ca-1dcd-45bb-8246-0c958e8def6f","expires_in":488,"scope":"read"}
>   2018-11-12 19:59:32.129 ERROR 23998 --- [nio-8090-exec-4]
>   o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for
>   servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
>   [Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 404 null]
>   with root cause
>
> org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 404 null     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:700)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:653)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:613)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:531)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]     at
>   OAuth.oAuth.client.controller.EmployeeController.showEmployees(EmployeeController.java:109)
>   ~[classes/:na]    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_181]   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_181]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_181]   at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:208)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   [na:1.8.0_181]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   [na:1.8.0_181]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_181]

Comment: you need to show some logs for the 500 error so that we can help and you need to implement some mapping for the /error path

Comment: I have added the log file..., cud u plz let me know?

Comment: the problem has been solved I changed the return type from "List<Employee>" to "ResponseEntity<Object>" in server controller "EmployeeController"